# Secure Data transport to external system

Tags: community, rest-api, integration, encryption, platform-encryption

I have a requirement to transmit the integration data via REST API to a legacy system. The client need is to have the data transmission done securely.

Wanted to check what would be the best approach in the apex call out

```
 1. base64 encode
 2. Crypto methods
```

I also seen somewhere as **Digital sign payload** with some keys for verify/trust the data at legacy system.

Can you suggest what should be the best to use and advantages so that I can have a discussion with my architect.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: REST calls are normally made using [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) which is in itself a secure channel. You only need to go further with a specific threat in mind.

Comment: The use case is to securely transmit sensitive data using salesforce security implementaion. So out of the two cited above which one should fit the need ?

Comment: I'm confused why HTTPS isn't sufficient. Base64 is not a security mechanism just an encoding mechanism (where anyone can decode). Encryption (to hide the data) and signing (to prove no data tampering) are security mechanisms.

Comment: Becasue it has some sensitive data (financial data) to be transmitted over to the legacy system, hence https is not sufficient.Couple of links which has some details about why https is not sufficient . Like  https://www.kaspersky.co.in/blog/https-does-not-mean-safe/12221/ also https://www.semrush.com/blog/https-a-modern-false-sense-of-security/

Comment: Based on my research , I think i will go with the crypto method and use a shared key vector for my encryption.